# Access Blocked Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

Is there any way to access the blocked cookies by the browser?
For example: When click on the lock/site information icon in the url search bar in the browser and go to cookies, there are two sections there Allowed and Blocked, I want to access and delete the cookies in the Blocked section using js.

Also when I access the brower document.cookie it only gives me access to the Allowed cookies.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6H5H.png)

Comment: they're blocked for a reason I would suspect - so, no, you can't access them using JS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.